# applescript icon problem (button_pressed is not definded)

Tags: macos, applescript

this script works fine until the commands of the buttons, can someone tell my why i doesent work?

it says "button_pressed is not definded"

```
display dialog "bla" with icon alias ((path to me) & "Contents:Resources:my.icns" as string) buttons {"blu", "bli", "blaa"} default button 3

if the button_pressed is "blu" then
    -- action for 1st button goes here
    say "blu"
else if the button_pressed is "bli" then
    -- action for 2nd button goes here
    say "bli"
else
    -- action for 3rd button goes here
    say "bla"
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way to do this is to use [`button returned`](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=AppleScript/2.1/en/as305.html):

```
display dialog "bla" with icon alias ((path to me) & "Contents:Resources:my.icns" as string) buttons {"blu", "bli", "blaa"} default button 3

set theResponse to button returned of the result

if theResponse is "blu" then
    -- action for 1st button goes here
    say "blu"
else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the variable `button_pressed` is NOT defined. All you have to do is add this line of code before the `if` block and it should work!

```
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
```

Variables (i.e. `button_pressed`) must **ALWAYS** be defined before they can be uesd. For example, this code will not function...

```
display dialog greeting --> ERROR
```

...while this one will:

```
set greeting to "Hello! I am now a defined variable!"
display dialog greeting
```